# Did Aharon speak Lashon Hara?

Tags: parashat-ki-tisa, lashon-hara-slander, aharon

In Parashat Ki Tisa ([Shemot 32:21-22](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0232.htm#21)) it seems that Aharon spoke Lashon Hara about Am Yisrael. Are there are any commentaries that discuss this? Do they discuss his punishment if he recieved one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbi Samson Rephael Hirsh - Shemos 32:22 - explains that actually Aharon took the blame on himself by saying that it was not the Jews fault that they made a Egel, they were in a bad situation and I assisted them.

> כי ברע הוא - אהרן לוקח את כל האשמה על עצמו, וגם אינו מספר על נסיונותיו
>   להשהותם במעשיהם. הוא אומר, כאשר בא העם בהחלטיותו, כפי שהוא תמיד בהיותו
>   במצב רע, נכנעתי לפניו מיד, ועשיתי כרצונו

Comment: Does he mention the _lashon-hara_ issue?

Comment: Not based on what I saw. However from what he writes I infer that there was no issue of Lashon Hara, quiet the opposite, Aharon was taking blame on himself.

Comment: Maybe. But he does say the people had "החלטיות" first. If someone sees Joe robbing a bank and (instead of saying the truth, that I tried to stop Joe) I say "it was Joe's idea, and I only helped", isn't that still _lashon hara_?

Comment: Lashon Hara does not include something which is well known. The Egel was known to all that the Jews did it, and Aharon was taking blame for it so how is that Lashon Hara? By robbing a bank you are telling the person Joe did it, where until now he had no idea Joe did it.